# ASP.NET MVC - binding select tag not binding to selectlist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Hello: I have a running web application using asp.net mvc the only issue is I am creating a dropdown list that comes from the database. When I run it, nothing shows up in the dropdown. I am told the issue is a binding select tag not binding to selectlist, though I cant seem to figure it out. Here is what I have so far and here is the error I get on Watch 1: **error CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context**

Index.cshtml:

```
    @model RiskApplication.Models.RiskApplicationModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>RiskPrescreen Application 2018</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Help", "ViewPage1")
</p>

<form asp-controller="DataForms" asp-action="Index" method="get" runat="server">
    <p>
        <select asp-for="Department" asp-items="@Model.owners">
            <option value="">-----------</option>
        </select>



        Application Name: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</form>
```

DataFormsController.cs:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string department, string searchString)
        {
            // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
            IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in db.AppOwner_DD
                                            orderby m.AppOwnerDes
                                            select m.AppOwnerDes;

            var dataForms = from m in db.DataForms
                            select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                dataForms = dataForms.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(department))
            {
                dataForms = dataForms.Where(x => x.AppOwner_DD.AppOwnerDes == department);
            }

            var movieGenreVM = new RiskApplicationModel();

            var list = await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync();
            movieGenreVM.owners = new SelectList( list );

            movieGenreVM.dataForms = await dataForms.ToListAsync();

            return View(movieGenreVM);
        }
```

RiskApplicationModel.cs:

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace RiskApplication.Models
{
    public class RiskApplicationModel
    {
        public List<DataForm> dataForms;
        public SelectList owners;
        public string department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors ? Or you see empty SELECT element ? Your code looks fine (Except you are using `Department` instead of `department`) If you are seeing an empty select element. put breakpoints and see whether you have valid items in `movieGenreVM.dataForms` after that line is executed

Comment: With the code you shared, you should not be getting "The name 'model' does not exist in the current context" error!

Comment: @Shyju the only error I am getting is on Watch 1: error CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context. I did fix Department to department but still when I run the program the dropdown list is empty. I did insert breakpoints and yes it does have valid items.

Comment: What is inside `list` ? Is it a list of string with more than one item ? (when you debug). If yes. your code should work

Comment: @Shyju yes it is a list of string which has more than one item in it.

Comment: @Shyju it is coming from a specific  column from a table in the DB

Comment: I just tried your code and it did render the SELECT element with those items.

Comment: What do you think is the issue on my side?

Comment: The code & information you shared perfectly works for me.